# Meteor template gets rendered twice

Tags: meteor

My template is getting rendered twice on first load. I notice this because in

```
Template.home.rendered = function() {
    console.log('rendered'); // => this is printed out twice
    console.log(Data.find({}).count()); // => this is initially 0, then 1 the second time
}
```

Furthermore, on the first load, no Data is available. Yet on the second load, the Data is there.

Does anyone know what this problem might be, and why the data only appears the second time?

Comment: this could be useful: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-know-when-my-subscription-is-ready-and-not-still-loading

Comment: Thanks @go-oleg. This looks promising, but how do I connect it with the `rendered` function for the template?

Comment: I'm just getting started with Meteor so this might not be the best approach...but you could create an `isDataReady` template helper that returns whether `Data` has been loaded, and put your `{{> home}}` in an `{{#if isDataReady}}...{{/if}}` block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a way to render the template when your data is available.

Using this template structure, the if block content, which happens to be the template displaying your data, will be rendered only when the myDataIsReady helper returns true. (thus triggering the rendered callback only once, with data immediately available).

```
<template name="displayData">
    <p>This is my data : {{this}}</p>
</template>

<template name="home">
    {{#if myDataIsReady}}
        {{#each data}}
            {{> displayData}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

You have to define a subscription handle (an object returned by Meteor.subscribe) in order to use it's reactive ready method : we'll reference it in the myDataIsReady helper to track data availability, and the helper will automatically rerun when the state of ready changes.

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    // this subscription should return your data subset
    myDataHandle=Meteor.subscribe("myData");
});

Template.home.myDataIsReady=function(){
    return myDataHandle.ready();
}

Template.home.data=function(){
    return Data.find({});
}
```

But that's quite annoying for such a simple task.
That's why I suggest using the Iron Router which makes things way simpler !

Add it to your project using "mrt add iron-router", then in a client/router.js and client/router.html, use this boilerplate code :

```
Router.configure({
    loadingTemplate:"loading"
});

Router.map(function(){
    this.route("home",{
        path:"/",
        // we indicate which subscription has to be marked ready in order to load the template
        waitOn:function(){
            return Meteor.subscribe("myData");
        }
        // the result of this function will become our target template data context
        data:function(){
            return Data.find({});
        }
    });
});

<template name="home">
    {{#each this}}
        {{> displayData}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="loading">
    <p>Data isn't ready yet...</p>
</template>
```

As you can see, the Iron Router allows us to specify simply what we painfully achieved manually in the first code example (waiting on a particular subscription to render a template), and of course we get free routing, loading mechanisme, layout management, etc...

Search the web for a complete iron-router tutorial (my code is untested, but I hope it is ok and should get you started), it's so awesome that it's gonna be merged to Meteor ultimately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `iron-router` sounds great. However currently I am using the `meteor-router` one and it looks like it doesn't have that feature in place.

Comment: Before Iron Router, there was essentially 2 routing solutions, meteor-router from Tom Coleman and mini-pages from Chris Mather. They eventually collaborated to develop the iron-router which as its name implies is a solid routing framework for Meteor. It is strongly advised to take the time needed to refactor your application into using the new router because it's much better and the previous one probably won't get maintained as core developer Tom Coleman is now working on iron-router.

Comment: Okay thanks for the explanation. Will be sure to do that as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I had a *body.html* in `/client` and a *appBody.html* in `/client/templates`, with, in iron router:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'appBody',
});
```

Both body templates were rendered (and happened to be the same). Obviously, the *body.html* in `/client` needed to be removed.